# Instagram Basic API: Is it possible to get the media_url from "CAROUSEL_ALBUM" in one query?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

If you are reading [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media#edges), you will read that you can add `children` to the `fields` query parameter. That means that if you have a media with the type `"CAROUSEL_ALBUM"` you will get the ids of the images as well.

Example CURL:

```
https://graph.instagram.com/me?access_token=<mytoken>&fields=id,media_type,media_url,children
```

The result:

```
...
     "id": "some-id",
     "media_type": "CAROUSEL_ALBUM",
     "media_url": "some-url",
     "children": {
        "data": [
           {
              "id": "another-id"
           },
           {
              "id": "other-id"
           }
        ]
     }
...
```

Is it possible to add media_url to the children's data? I don't really want to fetch everything in a loop...

Comment: Should be possible via Field Expansion. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media/children#reading, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Comment: @04FS love you it worked. You just need to add `children{media_url}`

Comment: @Shadrix I'm trying to achieve the same thing but can't. Could you add an answer to the question, showing the full request and a sample of the response?

Comment: @Mecha have a look :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Mecha I did this for PHP, but maybe you can read this

```php
    /**
     * Fetches media from the user
     *
     */
    public function fetchUserMedia(array $options, int $limit = 24): object
    {
        $query = http_build_query(array_merge([
            'limit' => $limit,
            'fields' => 'username,caption,id,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,children{media_url,thumbnail_url}',
            'access_token' => $this->token
        ], $options));


        return json_decode((string) ($this->client->get("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?{$query}"))->getBody());
    }
```

One output example is like this:

```
{
          "caption": "I\u2018m addicted to chia pudding, how about you? \ud83d\ude0d Layers of zingy lemon vanilla chia pudding, mango thyme infused coconut yoghurt and juicy fresh mango roses. \ud83e\udd24\nMade by \u0040addictedtodates \ud83c\udf4b\u2063\u2063\n\u2063\u2063\u2800\nAND now to our tagged picture of today \ud83d\ude0b\ud83d\ude0b Swipe left to see \u0040smoothie_yumm\u2019s coconut vanilla smoothie bowl topped with turmeric chia pudding \ud83e\udd29\n\u2800\nYou can find the recipe on her page \ud83d\udc9b\n\u2800\n\ud83c\udf31 Tag #avidofood or\u00a0\u0040avidofood\u00a0to be featured in the future!\n\u2800\n\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\u22c6\n#vegan #veganfood #veganfoodie #veganfoodshare #vegatarisch #veganpasta #vegandinner #veganeats #healthyfood #plantbased #plantbasedfood #veganpower #plantbaseddiet #veganiseasy #whatveganseat #forksoverknives #vegetarianrecipes #veganinspo #vegetarian #veganism #veganmeals #veganlife #veganlifestyle #veganlove #veganmealprep #veganrecipes #veganhealth #veganlunch",
          "id": "18039820117203997",
          "media_type": "CAROUSEL_ALBUM",
          "media_url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/71511404_203552310658678_3865693276191599368_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_oc=AQlet8stFGS32TTdBhXT4NNfpzd8eNq7oI0xilix4qyiVvt50avuk6RVotMgM-BUptmCrsVwLCGkPCc-sL7b-eAy&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=f1a700b4d021d2d577d54cd74f4838fa&oe=5E534677",
          "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B3-XRMOIWPW/",
          "username": "avidofood",
          "children": {
             "data": [
                {
                   "media_url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/71511404_203552310658678_3865693276191599368_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_oc=AQlet8stFGS32TTdBhXT4NNfpzd8eNq7oI0xilix4qyiVvt50avuk6RVotMgM-BUptmCrsVwLCGkPCc-sL7b-eAy&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=f1a700b4d021d2d577d54cd74f4838fa&oe=5E534677",
                   "id": "18041124712207922"
                },
                {
                   "media_url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/72483636_1251439178368296_6758852942587086206_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_oc=AQmVrktP2g7Z72WifVdu4z17OzwM7ZNFLln1e1ZQxjdUi-j79Ttf-i840mjYkOb-TW3Dwm39Gyoe3EefxwB7UydW&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=a07d3f51aa5eb5eb30697c4ad25d4e35&oe=5E60AEC3",
                   "id": "17851162897631131"
                }
             ]
          }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using PHP too. I see now why it didn't work for me. If you include invalid fields in field expansion for `children{...}`, instead of expanding `children.data` the API will instead replace all the main items in the response with their children. Must be a bug in the Graph API.

Comment: children{media_url} this part does the trick

Answer (score 7):

You just need to nest the fields in the children query params

```
/media?fields=id,media_url,children{media_url}&access_token=
```